# Remove text from JS output based on selection choice

Tags: javascript

I am writing a simple web app as a validation tool for work. Basically it validates a bunch of inputs and stops the agent from continuing if certain pitfalls are found. If everything looks correct, it will do some simple math and create a "receipt" stating that they have validated before approving charges and they paste the receipt into our in house database.

I've got everything to work, but I honestly have no idea how to make certain lines of the receipt appear only if needed. Below are snipits of the parts to kind of give you an idea:

HTML

```
<div class="md-form form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="totalEstimate">Total Estimate: </label>
        <input id="totalEstimate" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" max="100000"  placeholder="$0.00..." required readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="remainingLOL">LOL After Repairs:   </label>
        <input id="remainingLOL" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" max="100000"  placeholder="$0.00...">
        <p id="remainingLOLVal"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="diagOnly">Attempted/Diag:  </label>
        <input id="diagOnly" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" max="100000"  placeholder="$0.00..." disabled>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <div id="ppcDIAG" class="form group col-xs-2 col-md-2"><label>  </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label for="estApproved">Estimate Disposition </label>
        <select id="estApproved" class="custom-select" required>
            <option value="APPROVED">APPROVED</option>
            <option value="DENIED">DENIED</option>
            <option value="PENDING">PENDING</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
// Function to enable the input #diagOnly if denying or pending
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#estApproved').change(function() {
  if ( $('#estApproved').val() == "APPROVED") {
    $('#diagOnly').prop( "disabled", true );
  } else {
    $('#diagOnly').prop( "disabled", false );
    $('#diagOnly').prop( "required", true );
  } 
});
});


// The generated receipt that the agent will be pasting into in house database
function formReceiptTemplate() {
  $('#formReceipt').val(
    '\nTotal Estimate: $' + $('#totalEstimate').val()
    +'\n___________________________'
    +'\nEstimate: ' + $('#estApproved').val()
    +'\nAttempted Repair or Diagnostic Only Fees: ' + $('#diagOnly').val()
    +'\nPre-Approval Code: '
    +'\n'
    +'\n"As a reminder, all pre-approvals are contingent upon verification of your contracted or agreed upon service rates. Contracted rates supersede preliminary estimates and approvals".'
    +'\n '
    +'\n '    
  );
```

For this example, I want the "#diagOnly" input to only be active if "pending" or "denied" are selected and I want the entire line:

```
+'\nAttempted Repair or Diagnostic Only Fees: ' + $('#diagOnly').val()
```

to be missing from the final receipt as it should only be applicable if not "approved". I've searched everything I possibly could, but I've only been writing Javascript for about a month now and its a result of needing this tool. Not really sure where to look.

Apologies if this is super easy or a repeat. I really did look before creating an account. If you could at least point me in the right direction of where to research, I'll gladly continue there. Really look forward to learning more!

Comment: I highly suggest taking a look at Vue.js (or others, but this one's easier) to make this kind of roadblock disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Simplest" answer, just build the string piece by piece, with an `if` statement to check the state of the selection box:

```
function formReceiptTemplate() {
    var receipt = '\nTotal Estimate: $' + $('#totalEstimate').val()
        +'\n___________________________'
        +'\nEstimate: ' + $('#estApproved').val();

    if ($('#estApproved').val() !== 'APPROVED') {
        // X += Y is equivalent to x = x + y
        receipt += '\nAttempted Repair or Diagnostic Only Fees: ' + $('#diagOnly').val();
    }

    receipt += '\nPre-Approval Code: '
        +'\n'
        +'\n"As a reminder, all pre-approvals are contingent upon verification of your contracted or agreed upon service rates. Contracted rates supersede preliminary estimates and approvals".'
        +'\n '
        +'\n ';

    $('#formReceipt').val(receipt);
}
```

A cleaner solution would be to use a template library so you can avoid all of those crazy string concatenations, though. Also, you can be more efficient by storing your JQuery elements as variables, so you're not having to look them up over and over.